# Communicate to a sibling controller who is not explicitly defined

Tags: angularjs, controller, siblings, angularjs-rootscope, angular-broadcast

Hello I have the following situation

I have a controller with a Method, that sets a timeout and calls a modal along with other actions:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('GlobalController', GlobalController);

function GlobalController($scope, $rootScope, ....) {
  var vm = this;

      $scope.$on("callMethod", function(){ 
         vm.showModal();
      });
}
```

I want to be able to access to that specific **showModal()** method from any other controller in the application

So I have the following options

> **$emit(name, args);**
>
> Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope
>   hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

Using `$emit` I have to define the `GlobalController` as parent since its "upwards"

And:

> **$broadcast(name, args);**
>
> Dispatches an event name downwards to all
>   child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered
>   $rootScope.Scope listeners.

For any of those solutions i have to explicitly  define the controller within the application (i mean on the view) in order to use it be as a parent or child, is there any way to do this, (even if it's not a controller)?

Comment: Turn your controller into a service. Inject that service into any controller that needs to call showModal. Don't use $broadcast and $emit as a way to perform RPC between controllers.

Comment: I can't use scope in a service, and how do i use the [Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) controller within a service?